# Problema en autenticar GitHub en WSL de Windows

Tags: github, wsl, repositorio

Hola Alguien sabe como puedo autenticarme con GitHub en WSL de Windows al subir mi repo me pide los siguientes datos pongo mi user name y pass y no autentica, eh intentado con "git config ... user.name "rfhureh"" para el caso del name y pass y mail y me lo sigue pidiendo, Existe alguna otra forma de hacerlo y evitar este problema o como podria lucionarlo?

[image]

Comment: Quizás esto te sea de apoyo: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/tutorials/wsl-git Saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Espesificamente este es el mensaje de error **/mnt/c/Program\ Files/Git/mingw64/libexec/git-core/git-credential-manager-core.exe get: 1: /mnt/c/Program Files/Git/mingw64/libexec/git-core/git-credential-manager-core.exe: not found** al parecer se movieron de directorio las credenciales o algo por el estilo esto en WSL2 y como solucion es solo ejectura este comando y listo.

```
git config --global credential.helper "/mnt/c/Program\ Files/Git/mingw64/libexec/git-core/git-credential-wincred.exe"
```